# Slow mobile performance with jQuery slideUp, slideDown and toggle functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a small brochure page which in mobile view I want to have a number of containers that can expand via the slideDown/Up/toggle mechanism of jQuery to show more detail when the user clicks the appropriate area.

A quick [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ag2702oc/) of what I mean, and below is the JS code, I've not included the HTML and CSS except in the fiddle because it's quite lengthy:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    //mobile open
    $('#mob-one-show, #mob-two-show, #mob-three-show, #mob-four-show').click(function(){
        var arr = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var txt = "#"+arr[0]+"-"+arr[1]+"-text";
        $(this).toggle('slide', function(){
            $(txt).slideDown();
        });
    });

    //mobile close
    $('#close-one, #close-two, #close-three, #close-four').click(function(){
        var arr = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var txt = "#mob-"+arr[1]+"-text";
        var show = "#mob-"+arr[1]+"-show";
        $(txt).slideUp('slow');
        $(show).slideDown('slow');
    });

});
```

This is the exact styling and layout I am using, with BS3 as a framework and jQuery 1.11.2.

However in some devices, such as my own Samsung Galaxy S6, the slideUp and slideDown animations are horribly laggy. A little Google Fu suggested that it was iterating through classes on mobiles that might be the cause so I moved to IDs where possible, but there has been no improvement.

Anyone know why the animations might be so awkward? Just as a side note the animations on jsFiddle are still a bit laggy on my mobile, though the perform better than the live site despite being virtually the same code.

Comment: I would suggest you trying it with CSS-Animation instead of jquery .slideUp and .slideDown... Just add and remove classes with jquery... This should bring you a performance increase.

Comment: How mobile friendly are css animations? I've used them before for web but it still concerns me that not all browsers support them, had to jump through quite some hoops to have compatibility and graceful fallbacks.

Comment: You should read this quite interesting article about it, I think you will know a lot more after that: https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Comment: Well I tried CSS3 transitions, even using some cheats regarding forcing 3D translation to try to encourage the browser to use the GPU acceleration, but it seems that while there was some small improvement Chrome on the G6 at least is just laggy. Works fine on an iPhone 5C and 6.